# db2 - Query result to new table

Tags: java, sql, db2

Hello guys I need fill a table with el result of my query like....

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, X FROM OLDTABLE WHERE X=Y
```

I am a Java developer, my friends, RPG developers in the AS400. When they execute a a Query have a option to save the query result in a file

The option is called **SELECT output** and can choice **1 Display 2 Printer 3 File**

Can do this directly from a query? or is a native iSeries option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query will prompt you to replace an existing table.  Straight SQL won't prompt to replace an existing table so you have two scenarios (see note) .

If the output table doesn't exist, all you need is

```
create table newtable as (select <...> from oldtable) with data
```

If the output table already exists, all you need is an insert with sub-select.

```
Insert into newtable
Select <...>  from oldtable
```

**NOTE**
With the release of TR10 for v7.1 and TR2 for v7.2 in May 2015, IBM has added support the `OR REPLACE` clause to the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  So if you happen to be on those TRs or higher, you could simply use:

```
create or replace table newtable as (select <...> from oldtable) with data
```

Comment: we know this the user asked to create a table with output from sql.

Comment: @danny117, good catch...that's what I get for answering from mobile while on vacation.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a table with iseries sql

create a table with data.

```
create table abc as (select x,y,z from sometable where x=y) with data
```

create an empty table.

```
create table abc as (select x,y,z from sometable where x=y) data definition only
```

There is no output to printer using just sql.

Answer (score 0):

Could compile the SQL into a query manager query (CRTQMQRY) then run the query via (STRQMQRY).

To do that, put the query into the some sort of source file with a member type of TXT.  Get to a command line and run the CRTQMQRY command and create the output QMQRY.  STRQMQRY can be prompted and you can save the results in either an output file or a printout or look at it interactively.  If you submit it as a batch job, viewing the output interactively won't work too well.